# Difference between add() and create() functions and the functionsality of save() method

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to understand the difference between `.add()` and `.create()` functions through django documentation. 
As far as I have understood is that:

`add()` function with Foreign Key just updates the model and with m2m relation it does the bulk creation which eventually doesn't call for any save method.
`create` function will create the instance of the object and save it.

My doubt is:

1. What does actually save does? If only create an instance without saving it, what does it mean?
2. What is the main difference between `add()` and `create()` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answers will be next:

> What does actually save does? If only create an instance without saving it, what does it mean?

[save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) do actually create an instance in some cases. It works in one of this two ways:

1. If record primary key is set to a value (i.e., something else then None or empty string), Django executes an UPDATE.
2. If the object’s primary key is not set or if the UPDATE didn’t update anything, Django executes an INSERT.
   You can read more in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert)

> What is the main difference between add() and create() functions?

So, to simplify, `create()` uses save method with argument `force_insert` set to True in order to force Django to use only INSERT without falling back doing an UPDATE.

[add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) method is used to create M2M relations between records and that is a bit different from `create`. You can't use it while record you are linking other records to do not have a primary key.

So, this:

```
a = Model()
a.add(other_model_instance)
```

will raise an error, while this:

```
a = Model()
a.save() # or simply Model.objects.create()
a.add(other_model_instance)
```

will work.

Comment: Got it.What if I use ``.create()`` for same id, is it going to create a new row in database table with the same id?

Comment: You can explicitly set an primary key (I'm assuming you mean it by saying ID) only if you explicitly allowed that by your model. In this case you'll get DB error like `IntegrityConstraintViolation`. In another case primary key will be just automatically generated by Django.